# Carrierwave + Fog+ caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, carrierwave, fog

Scenario: We have a few users on the site who have previously uploaded a logo for their site. Recently, we changed the dimensions of this logo and would like all accounts to reflect this change (we've also removed retina_rails from our app). So we plan on making a migration to remove retina rails while at the same time looping through each account and re uploading the logos to normalize across all logos.

Currently, this is what the migration looks like:

```
class RemoveRetinaDimensionsFromAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :accounts, :retina_dimensions, :text
  end

  ActsAsTenant.configure.require_tenant = false
  Account.all.each do |account|
    if account.logo?
        account.logo.cache_stored_file!
        account.logo.retrieve_from_cache!(account.logo.cache_name)
            account.logo.recreate_versions!(:small, :small)
            account.save!
        end
  end
  ActsAsTenant.configure.require_tenant = true
end
```

This is what our carrierwave.rb file looks like:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.test?
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = false

  elsif Rails.env.development?
    config.storage = :file
    config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"

  elsif Rails.env.staging?
    config.storage = :fog
    config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
    config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',                                           # required
      :aws_access_key_id      => Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key_id,     # required
      :aws_secret_access_key  => Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret_access_key, # required
      :region                 => 'us-west-2'                                      # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    }
    config.fog_directory  = 'blvd-staging'                                        # required
    config.fog_public     = false 
 end
end
```

I've tried to follow the advice mentioned in this link https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Recreate-and-reprocess-your-files-stored-on-fog but it is not working. I've tested to make sure the cache is saving files, and it is. However, when I try and retrieve_from_cache! I'm unable to do so (as the cached file does not have a name).

This is what my cached files look like:

tmp
 uploads
  ##########-#####-####

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I did not run the desired code block within the change block inside the migration so the code was never being executed.